# Devise nested user signup form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise

I am having troubling creating a nested signup form for users that are using device authentication . The form is creating a new Owner but it doesn't create any new user.

Here are my models:

**User.rb**

```
class User <  ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :worker
  has_one :owner
end
```

**Owner.rb**

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
  attr_accessible :name, :website, :user_attributes, :user
end
```

A part of the owner controller:

```
class OwnersController < ApplicationController

  def show
   @owner = Owner.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
   @owner = Owner.new
  end

  def create
   @owner = Owner.create(params[:owner])
   if @owner.save
    flash[:notice] = "Owner created"
    redirect_to(:action => 'list')
   else
    render('new')
   end
  end

end
```

And my Owner form:

```
<%= link_to("<< Back to List", {:action => 'list'}, :class => 'back-link') %>

<div class="subject new">
  <h2>Create owner</h2>

  <%= form_for(:owner, :url => {:action => 'create'}, :html => {:multipart => true} ) do |f| %>
    </tr>
    <th>Name:</th>
    <td><%= f.text_field(:name) %></td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
    <th>Website:</th>
    <td><%= f.text_field(:website) %></td>
    </tr>
    <%= fields_for :user do |form| %>
      <%= form.text_field(:email) %>
      <%= form.password_field(:password) %>
      <%= form.password_field(:password_confirmation) %>
    <% end %>

    <div class="form-buttons">
      <%= submit_tag("Creat owner") %>
    </div>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

My development log

```
Started POST "/owners" for XXXXXX at 2011-01-23 21:16:59 +0100
  Processing by OwnersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“", "authenticity_token"=>"gA07ajItgkADpZ/rF5NM73AncUDWgb0Q2QJjXvMCSFY=", "user"=>{"email"=>"yes@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "owner"=>{"name"=>"asdas", "website"=>"www.test.com", "commit"=>"Create owner"}
  [1m[36mSQL (0.0ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.0ms)[0m  describe `owners`
  [1m[36mAREL (0.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO `owners` (`name`, `website`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) VALUES ('asdas', 'www.test.com','2011-01-23 20:17:00', '2011-01-23 20:17:00', NULL)[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (125.0ms)[0m  COMMIT
  [1m[36mSQL (0.0ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.0ms)[0m  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/owners/list
Completed 302 Found in 344ms
```

My new development log:

```
Started POST "/owners" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-01-24 16:41:02 +0100
  Processing by OwnersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“", "authenticity_token"=>"0TcWhIoUt9Qwrst8Zrj5tycd8LZ1VWdQ98YUSBWb9f4=", "owner"=>{"name"=>"sdfsdrfwrf", "user"=>{"email"=>"sdfdf@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}, "commit"=>"Create owner"}
Completed   in 375ms

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (User(#18210216) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#9451968)):
  app/controllers/owners_controller.rb:22:in `create'

Rendered C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (15.6ms)
Rendered C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (2062.5ms)
Rendered C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (2125.0ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need

```
<%= f.fields_for :user do |form| %>
```

where you have

```
<%= fields_for :user do |form| %>
```

---

(original answer)

Did you mean to have

```
@owner = Owner.create(params[:owner])
```

in your `create method? (Notice the lower case 'o' in`@owner`)

Comment: No it is not that. It creates a owner in owners table but it dosent create a new user.

Comment: I get this error: ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in OwnersController#create

User(#18757944) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#9440604)

Comment: Try putting `params[:owner].inspect` in your controller and see what the output is in your development log.

Comment: Try calling `@owner = Owner.new(params[:owner])` in your controller (instead of `create`), then `@owner.save`.

Comment: I have tried but it only create a owner in owners table. It dosent create a user with user params

Comment: For some reason, your `params` hash has `user` instead of `user_attributes`. Until you figure it out, as a quick and dirty fix, you should be able to call `User.create(params[:owner][:user])` to create the user. I don't see why the nested attributes aren't working correctly, though...